# Spring Security - How to add SavedRequest To Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security, request

Is there any way to add savedRequest to an Ajax request ? Or how can i redirect user to previous page(requested with Ajax) after login.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little bit, especially the latter part?

Comment: Client makes a ajax request "/checkout" path and gets redirect to login page, after successfully logged in i need to redirect client to "/checkout" path. But spring security does not keep savedRequests for ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you implemented post/redirect/get pattern. FlashMap attributes where you may want to have a look. As SaviNuclear stated it internally saves those attributes in session by default.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just try to catch the requested URL with `request.getQueryString` and put the value in session Object, when the user get validate after login then try to get the URL value to redirect to the actual page.